# UITableViewController wont display the cells im creating

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

first off I'm new to iOS development so this may be a simple issue,

I've got the following code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello!";
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    NSLog(@"Creating cell for %i:%i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row );

    return cell;
}
```

Now the table shows, but all the rows are blank. And the cells are being created. Not sure if it matters but im not using xib's or story boards so i dont know if its a styling issue.

I'm really in the dark here about what im doing. I've tried to follow a few tutorials and every time i end up at the same place with a blank table.

Thank you for all help! I'm open to ideas and possible tutorials etc.

Comment: Yeah, I get Creating cell for 0:0. Or if i set sections 1 and rows to 3 then i get:
Creating cell for 0:0
Creating cell for 0:1
Creating cell for 0:2
. TIL: stackoverflow comments dont support new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is more of a comment, but it's too big for the comment field.)

I've copied your methods exactly into my .m file, and it works. The rest of the file looks like this:

```
@interface MYViewController ()

@end

@implementation MYViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 640) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [table setDataSource:self];
    [table setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:table];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

I'm assuming you set the data source, since you're getting the NSLogs to print.

Comment: I didn't have any code in the viewDidLoad method, thank you so much, now time to rip apart every line and see what they do. Thank you !!

Comment: The UITableView Controller **data source** is where the program looks for how to load the table view cells. If you don't set your .m file as the data source, then it will look in the default data source - and it ignores your code. (Same goes for the **delegate** and performing `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the UITableView is not hidden, does not have a 0 alpha, and is above all other views?

Answer (score 0):

If the data you display has the possibility of changing when you go out and back into the view, I'd advice use of

```
[self.yourTableViewObject reloadData];
```

This will call all the delegate methods (getting the sections, individual cells) and repopulate your table view.